# "specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities" But Works In LINQPad

Tags: entity-framework

I have a class called DashboardGroupData

```
public class DashboardGroupData
{
    public int ConsignmentID {get;set;}
    public DateTime ActualManifestDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime PlannedLatestDeliveryDateTime {get;set;}
    public DateTime PlannedEarliestDeliveryDateTime {get;set;}
    public DateTime PlannedEarliestCollectionDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Status {get;set;}
    public int ServiceLevelID {get;set;}
    public double PalletWeight {get;set;}
    public int MaxMove {get;set;}
    public int LastMove { get; set; }
    public int PalletStatusID { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public int RequestDepotID { get; set; }
    public int CollectionDepotID { get; set; }
    public bool Collection { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following entity query:

```
                        groupConsignmentList = (from d in connectDB.vwDepotDashboards
                                            where depotAndSubDepots.Contains(d.DeliveryDepotID)
                                            && !incomplete.Contains(d.Status)
                                            && (!depotAndSubDepots.Contains(d.CollectionDepotID) || d.CustDirectToHub)
                                            && d.Sequence < (int)PalletStatusSequence.ICC
                                            && d.ActualManifestDate > validWindow
                                            && d.TransitHubID == hubID
                                            select new Models.DashboardGroupData()
                                            {
                                                ConsignmentID = d.ConsignmentID,
                                                ActualManifestDate = d.ActualManifestDate,
                                                PlannedLatestDeliveryDateTime = d.PlannedLatestDeliveryDateTime,
                                                PlannedEarliestDeliveryDateTime = d.PlannedEarliestDeliveryDateTime,
                                                Status = d.Status,
                                                PlannedEarliestCollectionDateTime = d.PlannedEarliestCollectionDateTime,
                                                ServiceLevelID = d.ServiceLevelID,
                                                PalletWeight = d.PalletWeight,
                                                PalletStatusID = d.PalletStatusID,
                                                Sequence = d.Sequence,
                                                Collection = d.Collection,
                                                RequestDepotID = d.RequestDepotID,
                                                MaxMove = connectDB.PalletMovements.Where(c => c.CreatedDateTime < manifestDayEnd && c.PalletID == d.PalletID && !(c.PalletMovementTypeID > 12 && c.PalletMovementTypeID < 19)).Max(c => (int?)c.PalletMovementTypeID) ?? 0
                                            });
```

When I try to do a further query (below) I get the "The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported" error:

```
var test = groupConsignmentList.Where(c => c.Sequence > 650  && c.Sequence < 1000).Select(c => c.ConsignmentID).ToList();
```

The same query written directly as a SQL query works perfectly, as do the above queries in LINQPad 5, using the same connection and entity model as the application.

I have tried renaming the field Sequence in the db to something that's not a SQL reserved word - but it didn't make any difference.

One clue: if I take the first query, ("groupConsignmentList =") and convert it to a list, in every member of the list, the value of Sequence is zero - whereas in LINQPad 5 it produces correct values.

The .Net framework is 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't realised that there is more than one assignment of a query to groupConsignmentList in the code - and the one I had added Sequence to wasn't the one used in this case.